# Avoid String concatenating for large log messages

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

One of the advantages of using something like slf4j is that it avoids String concatenation by using parameterized logging. However how do you avoid the performance hit when you have a long
log message?

```
logger.debug("This is a very long message that prints two values." +
    " However since the message is long, we still incur the performance hit" +
    " of String concatenation when logging {} and {} ", value1, value2);
```

Is there any way to avoid this performance cost, without using an ugly if block to check the log level?

```
 if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
     logger.debug("This is a very long message that prints two values." +
         " However since the message is long, we still incur the performance hit" +
         " of String concatenation when logging {} and {}", value1, value2);
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no String concatenation.

The compiler will have created a single long String literal for you.

Comment: That and even if there was concatenation, in a logging situation it's not a very critical hit on most areas for performance

Comment: @Rogue that depends on how much logging you do.

Comment: Well that's why I said "most" ;)

Comment: @Rogue - can you quantify "most"?